# Kohana 3 AUTH loggin issues on specific machines

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-auth

I have used Kohana on several projects now, as well as its included Authentication module with absolutely zero issues... until this particular client.

At first they could not log in to the site on an XP machine using IE8.  I did some digging and ended up adding this config file to application/config/session.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

/**
 * @package Session
 *
 * Session driver name.
 */
//$config['driver'] = 'native';

/**
 * Number of page loads before the session id is regenerated.
 * A value of 0 will disable automatic session id regeneration.
 */
//$config['regenerate'] = 0;


// KLUDGE: Windows XP SP3 running IE-7 and 8
// http://bit.ly/gPcV67
//$config['validate'] = 'ip_address';

    return array(
      'cookie' => array(
          'name' => 'session_cookie',
          'encrypted' => TRUE,
          'lifetime' => 43200,
      ),
      'native' => array(
          'name' => 'session_native',
          'encrypted' => TRUE,
          'lifetime' => 43200,
      ),
      'database' => array(
          'name' => 'session_database',
          'group' => 'default',
          'table' => 'sessions',
      ),
  );

?>
```

This worked for IE8 on the WinXP Machine

Now they have a laptop with Win7 that can not login with IE9 or Firefox 4.   I installed Chrome on the machine to make it workable till I could find the time to look into this further (Chrome worked fine while I was in front of the machine).  Today however I got a whole series of really pissed off emails claiming they could not get into the system again.

I can not reproduce this problem on any of my machines or browsers.  I am stumped, and I do not have a way to test changes I make.

Please Please Please HELP!
Thank you,
-David

Comment: Check how your cookies and session work. I think, `Auth::instance()->login()` works correctly and returns TRUE, but User object is missing after redirect (ussually its a cookie configuration problem).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a server issue to me, probably at the time of their login something denied their access (session not written?). I'd try with memcached or database sessions.